# What happened to "Tagged Questions" on the Stack Exchange site?

Tags: feature-request, support, tags, stack-exchange, usability

The latest redesign of the Stack Exchange homepage seems to have removed the "Tagged Questions" feature, which I think has decreased the usability and helpfulness of that page.

I think that the grouped, filtered tags were more helpful than the current main page content for experienced users.

Additionally, it seems that we have lost our old shared filters, forcing us to re-collect tags by hand and rebuild personal filters each time. Using the URL for a shared filter was much easier.

Is there any way that this functionality can be brought back? Or is there now a better way of quickly and easily finding the questions I'm interested in?

Comment: Erm, what? Tags still exist. So do favorite and ignored tags. And you can still *search* by tags and/or groups of tags.

Comment: Are you talking about the questions on the homepage that appear with an orange background? The ones that the system "automagically" determines are probably interesting questions for you, based on their tags? That still exists, too. Make sure you have the "interesting" tab selected.

Comment: @CodyGray - I say about ruined filters for tags. I see nothing "orange backround" on main page of SO, I don't want to see automated "suggestions". I want to have same easy access to [VCS filter](http://stackexchange.com/filters/35471/vcs) as it was to shared filter. I use only one, OK, but some old-timers, sure, could lose more amout more long filters

Comment: Oh. You're talking about the Stack Exchange site. You said Stack Overflow. I don't know anything about that, I don't use that site.

Comment: @CodyGray - oops, mea culpa. I said about **SE** redesign, yes

Comment: I tried to fix the question a little bit, that should help prevent some of those incoming downvotes. Hopefully I didn't inaccurately represent what you were trying to ask!

Comment: @CodyGray - you didn't. Aren't you looking for any chance, maybe, Chief Editor position :-)?

Comment: From my experience here, something that was removed was removed for a reason and won't be brought back. Most we can do is suggest some alternative and explain why it would be better than the removed feature. I'm not personally familiar with the "Tagged Questions" of SE main site so don't have any opinion, just giving general advice. As a side note, if you feel the edit of your question was not in place, you can always roll it back.

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd - I can't see good reasonable reasons for such usability and functionality flaws, except the desire to please even the lazy idiots. OK, owner has even these rights, without doubts, but announce this policy change in order to be able to save at least my reputation (in common sense, not local)

Answer (score 9):

Filters, aka Tagged Questions, are still around.

<strike>It's just that the "Tagged Questions" nav link was replaced with a "My Filters" sub-nav link under "Hot Questions". So, to access your filters, click "Hot Questions", then click "My Filters".</strike>

**EDIT**: The "Tagged Questions" link was replaced with a "Filtered Questions" link, which only appears in the nav for logged-in users.

This was done to make the homepage more noob-friendly, since Tagged Questions are arguably a power-user feature.

"Shared filters" also haven't gone anywhere. You can still share the url to any filter, and the recipient will be able to view and save the filter.

We did, however, remove the "Popular Filters" page. It received little traffic and wasn't working the way we hoped it might. The most popular filters always seemed odd and semi-random. For example, these were the top 3 filters at the time the page was removed.

1. **All Sites**: [*scm fortify*] [git*] [hgignore] [hgrc] [hgsubversion] [mercurial] [msysgit] [rtc] [subvers*] [svn] [tortoise*] [version] [version-control] [versioning]
2. **All Sites**: [emacs]
3. **All Sites**: [ccrc*] [clearcase*] [cleartool] [rational-team-concert] [rtc]

These are hardly useful to the average user, let alone a new Stack Exchange user who happened upon the "Tagged Questions" link in the top-level nav.

Comment: Maybe it could be linked from my SE profile instead? It doesn't seem to make a lot of sense to look for it under "hot questions". I never used to look at that page, but I use tag filters all the time.

Comment: Emmet, you don't understand core of my complainе and the main idea (two, actually). While in "Cody's edition" it's rather clean. **Pre-made shared common filters** was good for novice and amateur users, without this functionality you'll have [Automatically set tags when “Questions” is pressed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123915/automatically-set-tags-when-questions-is-pressed) type questions asked and asked again here. And answer (good) is more longer, than before redesign ("Find filter for your needs")

Comment: And I'm not blind moron, I **know**, there and how to find and use new filter's system, I just note: it's bad change  from usability POV (and design and promotion and positioning, but these are not my headache). You wrote answer for *brainless idiot*, **not for me**. Sorry, MISS. And +6 is a sign, what nobody from upvoters was able to understand my text and **useless of your answer in its context**. Remarkable result of "user-selection", yes

Comment: "The most popular filters always seemed odd and semi-random..." It's only your dabbler's impressions, **~600 subscribers and a lot more of hidden users of top-filters** had another opinion. Top first filter ("VCS") **nicely covered** questions around "First Class Citizens" (Git, Mercurial, SVN) of VCS-systems with **minimal amount** of skips and "noise". Top-Three around slightly **different wide area** also, where "favourite tags" **is not answer** (good). And keywords for filters was a result of long accurate collaborative filtering of pearls in a dunghill (at least I see it so)

Comment: Or put it on the Stack Exchange user page as a new tab?

Comment: @AnnaLear & Jarrod - Yea, profile tab link makes sense. Do you think we should bring back the Tagged Questions nav link (for logged in users only) too?

Comment: Scratch my idea - I like yours... a new tab for logged in users called "Filtered Questions."