# Automatically set tags when "Questions" is pressed

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Filter for Objective C only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117082/filter-for-objective-c-only)

Currently, I'm only interested in post regarding objective-c. Because of this, I would like the questions that show up to be of that tag, instantly. It annoys me that I have to press the tag every time I press "Questions". I think such a feature should be available, and it should be easy to change or remove the standard tags you want questions for. This would be a huge help ***for lots of people***

Comment: What about helping the rest of the community users?

Comment: "This would be a huge help to me" - You are not the only one using the site.  You should consider other users to when you make a feature-request.  Why don't you use the site for more than two days before calling other users names and wanting to change the site.  Further-more [Downvotes work differently on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: @wizH no need to be rude?

Comment: Ty for the link. I'm pretty sure other users also would like this feature... I just mentioned that as I feel this is very needed. However, my post is now edited.

Comment: You are very welcome - how about trying to be polite from now on?

Comment: If my comments were taken rude, I'm sorry. I just feel that saying I'm not helping the rest of the community users by only being able to help in the objective-c  section, is a weird observation? I guess the help in that section will still be viable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It annoys me that I have to press the tag every time I press "Questions".

- Use the "Favorite Tags" feature in the sidebar to add [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c)
- Instead of clicking "[Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions)", click the tag in the sidebar.

The tag link will remain in the sidebar for your convenience while viewing questions, as well as in the actual question's tags - so you have multiple routes to get back to the active objective-c posts.

It also helps to add the most popular tags that you aren't interested in to the "Ignored Tags", which will filter them out of the main feed.

It's really not that difficult, and most users here are interested in questions on many topics rather than just one, so the usefulness of this somewhat trivial feature request is very limited.

Comment: This tag exist on two sites here, BTW

Comment: I actually already had the tags as favorites ^^

Comment: [objective-c] isn't single tag for all objective-c questions, some variations detected, thus I created filter with `objective-c*`

Answer (score 1):

> Because of this, I would like the questions that show up to be of that tag, instantly

**Don't cry and DIY**

- SE Main page  - Hot Questions - My Filters - New Filter button
- In form:

1. Just question with objective-c* tag
2. Just these sites: SO + Programmers
3. Add Rule
4. Named - objective-c (or any name)
5. Save changes

[Rule for you](https://stackexchange.com/filters/35499/objective-c)

- When you'll want to use filter:

SE Main page  - Hot Questions - My Filters - select saved filter in list

Answer (score 1):

Ask your web browser to store a bookmark to an URL like this:

```
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug
```

It'll show you all the questions tagged [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) on meta. Configure the URL to the site and the tag as appropriate.